# JAVA: How to write to .xlsx with a low memory footprint

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, sxssf

I have an input .xlsx file f1 and I am trying to create another file f2 using f1 after some data modification.

Currently I am trying to use apache-poi streaming api to accomplish this task. The problem is that I am unable to accomplish this task with a low memory footprint. Here is my code snippet

```
import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader;

public static void streamingWriter()
{
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(50);
    workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
    try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("inputFile.xlsx"));
         Workbook inputWorkbook = StreamingReader.builder()
                 .rowCacheSize(50)
                 .bufferSize(512)
                 .open(inputStream)) {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Sheet newSheet;
        Row newRow;
        Cell newCell;
        for (Sheet sheet : inputWorkbook) {
            newSheet = workbook.createSheet();
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                newRow = newSheet.createRow(row.getRowNum());
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    newCell = newRow.createCell(cell.getColumnIndex());
                    copyCell(cell, newCell, workbook);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Mem2: " + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()));
        String fileName = "outputFile.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        System.out.println("Mem3: " + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()));
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        workbook.dispose();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error releasing respurces: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName() +
                e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Here are the run results -

**Mem1: 112MB**

**Mem2: 464MB**

**Mem3: 697MB**

Size of original "inputFile.xlsx" is 223KB.

As can be seen from the run results, calling workbook.write() is taking a lot of memory, is there a way to write to an excel file without using extra memory.

Main goal is to reduce both Mem2 and Mem3 of run results.

Comment: For very low memory, just use `CSV` instead. For lower memory, switch to `.xls`.

Comment: The `Office Open XML` file format (`*.xlsx`)  is simply a `ZIP` archive containing `XML` files. So the most memory saving approach to change that using `Java` is simply only opening the `ZIP` archive and manipulating the `XML` files in it directly using `StAX`. See examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3915431+stax. Of course that means high programming effort.

Comment: @Gagravarr, this is not an option for me since both the input and  output files are directly accessible by the end user and business requires support for .xlsx

Comment: @AxelRichter, thanks, this might help and I might have to go with this approach if I cannot find a higher level alternative.

Comment: Everyone wants everything for free and yesterday... Apache POI has no commercial sponsorship, only volunteers. Lower memory would be great, but it needs someone to pay for the development, and no-one wants to :(